# I'm using TensorFlow but all of my predictions are 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am modifying the Breast Cancer tutorial found on a [TensorFlow YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbDJqYzcwRXcxbHZHcjBiOEdzbm1OR3ZDWnp2QXxBQ3Jtc0tuemFINGdNTndYVEgwM2toTHQzN2hYZXFEQVUzVm9YQkdKRG85dlQ1bmhHOVJjZTU0d2dqZXJOakgtSkw0ZGdKMVRINGQ4ZFZ2YVBkZGxTc1Q5YlJialc1eXZRNTM4X1oyU1RDRC03WFBvYXFPeFU2Yw&q=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F2TLLoFg).  I am using my own data which seems similar to the example data, but I find that all of my predictions `Y_pred` are zero (0).  Why would this happen and how do I solve it?

I only made two changes to the Colab Notebook (and, of course, my data is different):

- I changed the input_dim to 64 (`input_dim = 64`)
- The very end of the program I changed to (which worked in the example project, so I believe there is no error here):

  ```
  Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

  for i in range(len(Y_pred)):
      print(Y_pred[i])
  ```
- I'm using my own data.  The input data are rows of 64 comma-separated integers from 0 to 99.  The output is always a decimal number between -1 and 1.  Furthermore, the data is meaningful, in that there is some correlation between the 64 inputs and the output.

My loss is very high.  Maybe this is another clue to the problem:

```
    classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 1, epochs = 2)

    Epoch 1/2
    21267/21267 [==============================] - 25s 1ms/step - loss: -346672161.6313

    Epoch 2/2
    21267/21267 [==============================] - 23s 1ms/step - loss: -25468477308.2686

    <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fd395bd74d0>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. No one can help here with the amount of information (not) given, please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide your model and layers? Have you tried different loss functions, optimizers? How large is your dataset? Is it the same size as the one you watched in the video?

Comment: It could be different things, wrong loss function, unbalanced data, too high learning rate, etc.

Comment: A very good exercise that will help you debug: start with a database of, say, only 2 images (and have the train set be the same as the validation set). If your model is not capable to quickly overfit to perfect results, then you have some problem. Otherwise you know the basics are sound and you can start to think about all the other aspects others have pointed out already.

Comment: Thank you to desertnaut, Bobby Ocean, VincFort, and Pablo for your responses.  Clearly this is more complicated than I thought.  I will research these answers and try as many as I can.  Your input is much appreciated.

Comment: With your help, I figured out how to at least make progress.  It turns out that I was using the sigmoid activation on my last layer.  However, I had scaled my outputs from -1 to 1.  All I needed to do is rescale my outputs from 0 to 1, and now the ANN is at least giving predictions that are not 0, and my loss reduces from 0.7314 to 0.6145 in the first two epochs.  (I may still have a lot to do and a lot to learn, but at least it is somewhat working.)